# Syntax error in INSERT statement with Access and pyodbc

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm having a hard time getting an SQL insert into an Access database using pyodbc via Python. Each attempt throws an "invalid syntax error".

```
 import pyodbc

 ney = 'data1'
 soy = 'data2'

 MDBA = 'C:/db/dbBase.mdb'; DRVA = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'; PWDA = 'pw'

 # connect to db
 cona = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}'.format(DRVA,MDBA,PWDA))
 cura = cona.cursor()
 SQL = ("""insert into [db1](col1, col2) values ('ney', 'soy')""") 
 #SQL = ("insert into db1(col1, col2values (?, ?)", ney, soy)

 cura.execute(SQL)
 cona.commit()
```

I was able to do a SELECT statement, so what would be the correct syntax for an INSERT?

Comment: The commented out SQL is a syntax error with no closing parenthesis or space before `values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied-and-pasted your code into IDLE and it did not throw an error for me. However, it also inserted the literal values 'ney' and 'soy' into the table. In order to get the *values* of those variables you need to use a parameterized query, like this:

```python
sql = "insert into [db1] (col1, col2) values (?, ?)"
params = (ney, soy)  # tuple containing parameter values
cura.execute(sql, params)
```